# Spring Security throwing "Reason: Bad credentials" error in UI but correctly finding user during login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've exhausted every SO post and blog entry I could find trying to figure out what I've done wrong. So, now I'm asking for your help. I'm building a Spring Boot app and leveraging Spring Security for user management/authentication. I think I've set everything up correctly, but during login Spring Security redirects to the login failure URL (/login?error) every time, throwing the error:

***Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
Reason: Bad credentials***

There is nothing telling or useful in the server logs. As part of debugging, I added a bunch of logging which confirmed that:

1. The user is being found in the database (via email, with `usernameParameter` set to email in config
2. Spring Security's `userDetails.User` creates the correct user from its `new` constructor (I've logged the details of the user)

I am new to the framework so it's possible I'm overlooking something, which is where I would really appreciate your help. I've included my security config and user service below (I've cleared out logging to clean it up for your reading)--let me know if any other pieces would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Resource(name = "userService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().usernameParameter("email").defaultSuccessUrl("/register_success");
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();
    super.configure(http);
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
                            throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

// Define this bean so autowired can find and use it (fixes complaining error)
@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

private static final String LOG_TAG = UserService.class.getSimpleName();
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LOG_TAG);

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

// Must provide email address as username argument
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no user with this email address.");
    }
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User springUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), getAuthority());
    return springUser;
}

public User findByEmail(String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
}

public User findByConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken) {
    return userRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
}

@Transactional
public List<User> findAll() {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    return (List<User>) criteria.list();
}

public void saveUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

//TODO: Figure out how to use this properly
public List getAuthority() {
    return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the password that store in your database ? The password must be store in the database with `BcryptPassword` format. The password should not store as the normal string.

Comment: @Cataclysm Yes, I've logged the password and viewed it directly in the database. It is indeed encoded.

Comment: @Cataclysm I've also now verified that the raw password input matches the decrypted password from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PasswordEncoder to encrypt passwords when adding new users.

like this:

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
public void saveUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: I encrypt the password in the registration controller, when the user is being prepared for save.

`// Set the new password
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(requestParams.get("password").toString()));`